# Angular 4 RequestOption object not assignable for post method

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trouble with these codes, I created a header with following code block

```
headers.append("Authorization",btoa(username+":"+password));

var requestOptions = new RequestOptions({headers:headers});
```

But if I try use this in a post method in that

```
return this.http.post(url,JSON.stringify({username,password}),requestOptions)
    .map(res=>res.json())
    .map(res=>{
      if(res){
        localStorage.setItem("isLogged",res);
        this.loggedIn =true;
      }
      return res;
    });
```

I take this error message

```
Typescript Error
Argument of type 'RequestOptions' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'. Types of property 'headers' are incompatible. Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type 'HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }'. Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type '{ [header: string]: string | string[]; }'. Index signature is missing in type 'Headers'.
```

I tried change Header() to HttpHeader() but it didn't help. What is the problem?

**UPDATED**

I removed requestOptions object then I created headers from HttpHeaders()

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
```

and use this headers value in post method in that

```
return this.http.post(url,JSON.stringify({username,password}), { options: { headers: headers; } })
    .map(res=>res.json())
    .map(res=>{
      if(res){
        localStorage.setItem("isLogged",res);
        this.loggedIn =true;
      }
      return res;
    });
```

then get this error

```
[ts]
Argument of type '{ options: { headers: HttpHeaders; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'options' does not exist in type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.
```

I also tried this

```
return this.http.post(url,JSON.stringify({username,password}), { headers: headers })
    .map(res=>res.json())
    .map(res=>{
      if(res){
        localStorage.setItem("isLogged",res);
        this.loggedIn =true;
      }
      return res;
    });
```

then I got an error on first ".map"

```
[ts] Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `RequestOptions` class was to be used with the deprecated **[Http](https://angular.io/api/http/Http)** module, and since you're getting this error I'd assume you're using the **[HttpClient](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient)** module.

If you want to set `headers` through `options` as shown in your code, you can use something like this (simplified version of what is shown in the Angular [docs](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#request)):

```
request(url, { body }, { options: { headers?: HttpHeaders; } })
```

But, you can also set `headers` directly, without using options. That would look something like this:

```
    request(url, { body }, { headers?: HttpHeaders; } )
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, here is the my constructor:

constructor(@Inject('apiUrl') private apiUrl, public http: HttpClient) { }

I didn't understand, I am also using HttpClient. I tried that with your tips but I guess I did something wrong again.

Comment: The constructor looks good. Can you update your http request in the question to show how it looks now?

Comment: Okay, I deleted requestOptions, and let headers = new HttpHeaders(); use that for headers. I didn't change append line then try this: return this.http.post(url,JSON.stringify({username,password}), { options: { headers?: headers; } }) I guess İt's so wrong...

Comment: It should be close, you won't need the `?` (Elvis operator) in your actual request, it's just for the definition of the `HttpHeaders` class. Can you post the updated code in the initial question box so I can see it all together? Also, the current error that is appearing.

Comment: Okay, so the first version is throwing an error b/c if you use options, you'll have to reformat it to have your `body` and `header` inside the options, seen [here](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#request). Your second attempt is resulting in a successful request, since the error is being thrown here: `.map(res=>res.json())`. That last error is a diff issue.

Comment: Is HttpHeader template okay?

Comment: Yeah, your version that is posted after "I also tried this" is good, the request is working with no error. That error is being thrown in your handling of the response. Without being able to see the whole file, it appears that error is being thrown b/c you haven't added `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';` where you're declaring your imports for the file.

Comment: I imported 'rxjs/add/operator/map'; but I got an error from json() on .map(res=>res.json()), It will make me sick, thanks for your helps :)

Comment: const options = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': this.sessionTokenForSuccessfullyLoggedUser,
                'Accept': contentType
            }),
            responseType: 'blob'
        }
        //  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob });
        return this.http.get(urlPath, options)

error in options:   Types of property 'responseType' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"json"'.

Answer (score 6):

@angular/http is deprecated

Use @angular/common/http instead

```
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

const httpOptions = {
     headers: new HttpHeaders({
     'Content-Type':  'application/json',
     'Authorization': 'my-auth-token'
    })
};


addHero (hero: Hero): Observable<Hero> {
     return this.http.post<Hero>(this.heroesUrl, hero, httpOptions)
     .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError('addHero', hero))
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import {
    Http,
    Response,
    Headers,
    RequestOptions
 } from '@angular/http'; 

private headers = new Headers({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': localStorage.getItem('token')
  });
  private options = new RequestOptions({
    headers: this.headers
  });

private user: User;

constructor(private _http: Http) {}

getUserService() {
    return this._http.get(this.baseUrl + '/user', this.options)
      .map((response: Response) => response.json(),
      error => error.json('erreur dans lurl'));
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, how can I set 'Authorization' head to username + ' : '+' password ?

Comment: { 'Authorization': `${username}:${password}` }

Answer (score 0):

**In services**

> In the simple way passing multiple arguments

```
export interface Doctor {

       license1d1: number;
       firstname1: string;
       experience1: number;
       fee1: number;
       qualification1: string;
       lastname1: string;
       specialization1: string;    }






     getDoctorsBydepartment(Hosp: number, Dept: number): Observable<Doctor[]> {

           const url = 'http://192.168.75.15:8080/Booking/rest/List.do?' 
           ClinicID='+Hosp+'&DeptID='+Dept;
           return this.http.get<Doctor[]>(url).pipe()

        }
```